# Authentication failure while connecting to a URL through HTTPURLConnection

Tags: get, sms, httpurlconnection

I wish to send sms through my java application using some third party API. While running the below code snippet with my api credentials (variable 'type' contains the url and the 'params' hold the parameters of the message like sender, receiver,message etc...), it shows **Authentication failure** while getting the response back. But using the same credentials in browser, it works properly and sends message. Please help me in figuring out the reason for the authentication failure.

```
    uri = new URI(  type, params , null );
    URL url = uri.toURL();
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    conn= (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.connect();
    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println(" The Response Code  after Sending the SMS : "+responseCode);
    InputStream isr = ((responseCode>= 200)&&(responseCode< 300)) ? conn.getInputStream() : conn.getErrorStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr));
    String line;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");
    while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        result.append(line);
    }
    String response = result.toString();
    System.out.println("The Response after Sending the SMS : "+response);
```

Comment: I don’t see any explicit attempt at authentication in your code … // What does the documentation of the gateway you are using have to say about this?

Comment: I gave the authentication key of the gateway in the parameters. Url and parameters looks like below,        **Url:**https://api.msg91.com/api/sendhttp.php **Parameters:**mobile=XXX&authkey=YYY&message=ZZZ&sender=ABC